ModuleNotFoundError: no module named "StrucPy" - Internal package
When running the developed package "StrucPy" from the folder "Testfiles"- it says "Module Not Found". The same "testfile1" effectively import "StrucPy" when placed outside the folder "Testfiles".  I tried everything, but it's not working. What should I do to make it work.
init.py folder contains- "from StrucPy import RCFA"
Here is the screenshot of the folder arrangement and locations.


I think there is a problem in importing. you are trying to import a file that is 1 level higher in the hierarchy. So, in testfile1.py instead of from StrucPy.RCFA import RCF write from ..StrucPy.RCFA import RCF. Hope it will work.
